# Erro ao fazer Build do Jar

Tags: java, maven, exceção, intellij-idea

Estou tentando fazer o *build* do meu primeiro JAR usando o *IntelliJ* e *Maven* para gerenciar as dependências. Criei o artefato e executei *build*, porém quando executo o programa recebo a seguinte `exception`:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.SecurityException: Invalid signature file d
igest for Manifest main attributes
        at sun.security.util.SignatureFileVerifier.processImpl(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.util.SignatureFileVerifier.process(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.jar.JarVerifier.processEntry(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.jar.JarVerifier.update(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.jar.JarFile.initializeVerifier(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.jar.JarFile.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.JarIndex.getJarIndex(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader.ensureOpen(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.URLClassPath$3.run(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.URLClassPath$3.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at sun.misc.URLClassPath.getLoader(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.URLClassPath.getLoader(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.URLClassPath.getResource(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
```

Tentei deletar a pasta *META-INF*, mas também não adiantou.

**Edição:**
Fiz um teste e consegui executar o meu JAR, contando que as bibliotecas não estejam extraídas dentro dele e sim fora do JAR.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>groupId</groupId>
    <artifactId>IRMaven</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.tika</groupId>
                <artifactId>tika-app</artifactId>
                <version>1.5</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.17</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
                <artifactId>lucene-core</artifactId>
                <version>4.7.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
                <artifactId>lucene-analyzers-common</artifactId>
                <version>4.7.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
                <artifactId>lucene-queryparser</artifactId>
                <version>4.7.0</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Qual é o erro que dá ao executar o mvn clean install ?

Comment: Não acontece nenhum erro

Comment: Qual é a IDE que está utilizando?

Comment: Estou usando IntelliJ

Comment: poderia editar sua pergunta e mostrar seu `pom.xml`?

Comment: @Math tá na mão!

Comment: Você tá usando Swing? Como você conseguiu fazer seu jar rodar sendo que você não indicou qual é a classe principal no pom.xml?

Comment: Sim estou usando swing. Bom, daí eu não sei, ele rodou, talvez por estar aparecendo no Manifest.

Comment: @Strokes se não for pedir muito poderia incluir o MANIFEST.MF no corpo da sua pergunta?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Boas,

Eu penso (visto que não tenho acesso ao teu ficheiro Manifest) que pode ser uma das seguintes situações, porque de facto o que o erro indica é que existe um conflito no ficheiro das assinaturas.

`Invalid signature file digest for Manifest main attributes`

## Soluções:

1. Está a incluir um jar com uma assinatura diferente do jar que está criando e como tal está a fazer conflito. Para isto a solução é adiciona-lo no Manifest com dependência externa que já me aconteceu mas foi a trabalhar com o Eclipse, em principio deve conseguir fazer isso com GUI se for as opções do IntelliJ ou se não terá que modificar mesmo o Manifest manualmente do Maven;
2. A segunda hipótese é também um conflito na assinatura actual com a que quer gerar em que a solução seria remover a pasta META-INF em todos os jars que está a utilizar, gerar  novamente o Manifest ou se este se manteve ver se os jars estão adicionados la (se não adiciona-los novamente) e voltar a assinar todos os jars com a sua assinatura, com excepção das livrarias externas em que deverá aplicar a solução 1;
3. A terceira possibilidade, apesar de ser a menos provável é que nas opções do IntelliJ tem que quer criar o Jar com assinatura enquanto ao mesmo tempo não está a acrescentar assinatura nenhuma ao Jar (no Manifest).

## Conclusão:

O que está a causar o problema é a opção de segurança do Jar que são as assinaturas, isto para proteger o programador de plágio, como tal todos os Jars de um projecto têm de ter a mesma assinatura ou os que não são do programador deverão ser adicionadas como uma livraria externa.

O que sugiro é que tente aplicar as soluções dadas e também ler as referências adicionadas a baixo e caso isto não resolver o seu problema terá que acrescentar mais detalhes sobre o seu projecto a sua questão, como por exemplo, o ficheiro Manifest, livrarias adicionadas (externas ou não), como aplicou as assinaturas, etc.

## Referências:

- http://www.mail-archive.com/itext-questions@lists.sourceforge.net/msg34999.html
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19002777/java-lang-securityexception-invalid-signature-file-digest-for-manifest-main-att
- http://jehy.ru/articles/2013/12/13/invalid-signature-file-digest-for-manifest-main-attributes/
- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/signing.html
- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/SecurityToolsSummary.html
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9592057/error-while-creating-consolidated-jar-file-no-manifiest-section-for-signature

## Edição 29-04-14:

Apôs da questão, nos comentários, se dá para adicionar todas as dependências em ficheiros num só posso responder que o Maven tem um plugin que permite fazer isso. O que o plugin faz é encapsular as dependências todas num ficheiro jar só (como se criasse um zip). Nota: Alguns programas conseguem "desempacotar" esse jar, por se não quer que ninguém veja as dependências por motivos de segurança deverá estudar bem as opções de segurança do plugin. Como eu próprio nunca o utilizei, não me sinto 100% a vontade com este plugin e pelo que não o acrescentei logo à resposta.

Esta solução consiste em acrescentar ao pom.xml o plugin `maven-assembly-plugin` indicando que é um `jar-with-dependencies`.

Assim sendo tem de adicionar isto aos  que deverão estar dentro de  no pom.xml:

```
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>single</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
      <descriptorRefs>
        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
      </descriptorRefs>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

No seu pom.xml em concreto o seguinte deveria funcionar:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>groupId</groupId>
    <artifactId>IRMaven</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.tika</groupId>
                <artifactId>tika-app</artifactId>
                <version>1.5</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.17</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
                <artifactId>lucene-core</artifactId>
                <version>4.7.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
                <artifactId>lucene-analyzers-common</artifactId>
                <version>4.7.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
                <artifactId>lucene-queryparser</artifactId>
                <version>4.7.0</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>

        <!-- Inicio: As alterações que efectuei -->
        <build>
            <plugins>
                 <plugin>
                      <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                      <executions>
                           <execution>
                                <phase>package</phase>
                                <goals>
                                     <goal>single</goal>
                                </goals>
                           </execution>
                      </executions>
                      <configuration>
                           <descriptorRefs>
                                <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                           </descriptorRefs>
                      </configuration>
                 </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
        <!-- Fim: As alterações que efectuei -->
</project>
```

Espero que seja este o resultado que pretende, fico a espera de feedback.

Referências utilizadas nesta edição:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1729054/including-dependencies-in-a-jar-with-maven
- http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/introduction.html

Comment: É muito estranho isso, pois apesar de eu possuir um manifest as únicas informações que possuo nele são: `Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: Executor`
Não possuo nenhuma assinatura adicionada.

Comment: Deve ter a ver com as dependências então. Aposto na solução 1.

Edição: Vi que foi essa a solução que funcionou. O que aconteceu era que o jar que estava a criar não tinha assinatura e ao incluir algum jar/livraria que tenha uma assinatura, existirá conflito, como tal, tem de adiciona-las como dependência externa ao seu projecto.

Comment: Então essas bibliotecas que estou usando não podem ser extraídas dentro do meu JAR?

Comment: De uma forma geral só é possivel se forem do mesmo autor(es), tendo a mesma chave. No entanto, ja tinha ouvido dum plugin para o maven que permite assemblar um projecto inteiro num jar só (também existem outros formatos) que se chama `maven-assembly-plugin`.